# How to assign function inputs in map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, partial

I have a data frame of parameter values, in R, so for example

```
scenarios <- data.frame(max_day=c(100,200,300),max_cases=c(100,100,100),scale=c(2,3,2))
```

and I also have a function *scenario_sim* which has inputs *max_day, max_cases, k, no_sims* and *scale*. I first partially fill in the function inputs using the partial function

```
sim_with_params <- purrr::partial(scenario_sim, k=0, no_sims=5)
```

I then want to apply the function using each row of the data frame as the remaining inputs. I tried using map but am not sure how to pass the remaining parameters as they are not necessarily in order and also, the partially filled in ones change.

```
results <- map(scenarios, sim_with_params, ...)
```

This example is obviously much simpler than the real ones I am using also. The scenario_sim function has a lot of inputs, some of which are left as NULL sometimes too. I would very much appreciate some suggestions on the best way to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using base R function `do.call` and `Map`:

```
do.call(Map, c(f = sim_with_params, scenarios, k=0, no_sims = 5))
```